# How to get one int value from string in request response and skip the other ones

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I have a problem with reading 1 value from browser console.

it looks like that

[image: screenshot]

I want to get the "xp" value and I did it, but only in that one case.

```
const quests = result.data.quests;
console.log(quests[1]);
var exp = quests[1].rewards;
var xp = exp.replaceAll('{"coins":3,"xp":', "");
var xp = xp.replaceAll(',"honor":0,"premium":0,"statPoints":0,"item":0}', "");
var xp = parseInt(xp);
console.log(xp);
```

In other cases the values of course will be different and it won't work, so how can I make the program get te same result every time?

Comment: `rewards` is a JSON string. Parse it as JSON, and access the `xp` value.